# Array static allocation

Tags: c, arrays

```
int num = atoi(argv[1]);
unsigned long times[num];
```

I have this code and I assumed it won't compile because I am trying to allocate the array using a value from a command line argument, which compiler doesn't know at the compile time. 
But I compiled this code and it worked.
Can someone explain what is going on here??
Am I misunderstanding the basic concept of static allocation??

Comment: C99 supports [*variable-length arrays*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), as seen here.

Comment: essentially it's up to the compiler to determine a way of allocating the array at runtime, rather than at compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C99 allows to allocate an array with a var. This is called **variable length arrays** aka **VLA**

I don't have the C99 in my hand, the section is 6.7.5.2 in C99, and the following links are from the internet.

[vla - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

[c99 - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)

be aware that vla is not supported in c++, more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)